# RNeo4j startGraph gives 'Error: Success: (200) OK'

Tags: r-neo4j

When using this example from http://nicolewhite.github.io/2014/06/30/create-shiny-app-neo4j-graphene.html ... the startGraph function gives an error

```
> library(RNeo4j)
> graph = startGraph("http://localhost:7474/db/data/") 
  Error: Success: (200) OK
> importSample(graph, "dfw")
  Error in importSample(graph, "dfw") : object 'graph' not found
>
```

The neo4j community edition server, version 2.3.2, is running and authentication is turned off in the neo4j-server.properties file with this statement:
'dbms.security.auth_enabled=false'

Has anybody else experienced this problem and have a solution for it please?

Comment: It's likely related to a breaking change in `httr` between versions 1.0.0 and 1.1.0. There's an issue for it here and I'm looking into it: https://github.com/nicolewhite/RNeo4j/issues/47 The temporary solution is for you to fall back to `httr` v1.0.0.

Comment: Thank you for fixing this so quickly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This was a bug introduced by a breaking change between httr v1.0.0 and httr v1.1.0. It's been [fixed](https://github.com/nicolewhite/RNeo4j/commit/9a8f35366dc57a1becd5a4189ca1489be90f429b) in RNeo4j v1.6.3, now available on CRAN. Update RNeo4j with `install.packages("RNeo4j")` and restart R.